# Change search setting shopware 6 not using and nor or function

Tags: search, shopware, shopware6

Is there an easy way to change the search function in Shopware 6, currently it uses or function but is really need it to find it specific. So entering 16x24x5 only returns that value, not adding more non-related sizes?

Comment: Anyone a idea on how to change this?